# JS not added to head loaded and phtml not loaded

Tags: magento-1.7, template, layout, javascript

I am creating a very simple custom module to display an inline popup in my store.

The problem is that the my additional JS doesn't seem to be added, and the phtml file is not loaded. Both are in `newsletterpopup.xml`.

What am I missing?

**\app\etc\modules\Mav_NewsletterPopUp.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<config>
      <modules>
            <Mav_NewsletterPopUp>
                  <active>true</active>
                  <codePool>local</codePool>
            </Mav_NewsletterPopUp>
      </modules>
</config>
```

**\app\code\local\Mav\NewsletterPopUp\etc\config.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>

<config>
      <modules>
            <Mav_NewsletterPopUp>
                  <version>0.0.1</version>
            </Mav_NewsletterPopUp>
      <modules>
      <frontend>
            <layout>
                  <updates>
                        <newsletterpopup>
                              <file>newsletterpopup.xml</file>
                        </newsletterpopup>
                  </updates>
            </layout>
      </frontend>
</config>
```

**\app\design\frontend\MY_THEME_HERE\default\layout\newsletterpopup.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<layout version="0.1.0">
    <default>
        <reference name="head">
            <action method="addJs"><script>mav/cookie/jquery.cookie.js</script></action>
        </reference>
        <reference name="before_body_end">
            <block type="core/template" name="newsletter_popup" as="newsletter_popup" template="mav/newsletter-popup.phtml" />
        </reference>
    </default>
</layout>
```

**\app\design\frontend\MY_THEME_HERE\default\template\mav\newsletter-popup.phtml**

```
<!-- HTML for popup shall appear here -->
```

**\js\mav\cookie\jquery.cookie.js**

```
//taken from http://www.demacmedia.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/08/jquery-files-for-popup1.zip
```

Comment: please try to remove your cache

Comment: i have already cleared cache, caching is also disabled

Comment: you put your js files in js folder or in your skin folder ?

Comment: no, in /js folder. specifically: /js/mav/cookie/jquery.cookie.js

Comment: Then it will be working fine. Check permission and as well as copy that addjs code in page.xml and test will be aadded or not

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there is problem with `closing tag of </modules>` can you update xml with added closing tag

```
<config>
      <modules>
            <Mav_NewsletterPopUp>
                  <version>0.0.1</version>
            </Mav_NewsletterPopUp>
      </modules>
      <frontend>
            <layout>
                  <updates>
                        <newsletterpopup>
                              <file>newsletterpopup.xml</file>
                        </newsletterpopup>
                  </updates>
            </layout>
      </frontend>
</config>
```